# fullcalendar events not displayed after next

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to replace my old calendar (DHX) by full calendar.

I use the demo code, and i managed to display my json events.

The issue i have is when i click to NEXT, or PEV.
I don,t see the others events.

I load all 2019 events in one shot for the next events should be displaying.

HTML :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>FTS Team</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script src="calendarv2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/bower_components/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- For Calendar -->
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/gcal.js"></script>      
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css">  

<!-- For Modal Windows -->
<script src="lib/bootstrap/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>    
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="span12 calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

The JS is :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $compile, uiCalendarConfig) 
{

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();


    /* event source that contains custom events on the scope */
    $scope.events = [{title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date(y, m, 1)}];

    $http.get('rest/event/').success(function(data) {
            $scope.myEvents = data;

            data.forEach(function(entry) {
                var d1 = new Date(entry["dateB"]);
                var d2 = new Date(entry["dateE"]);

                var myEvent = {title: entry["title"],start: d1, end: d2, allDay: true};
                if ( d1.getFullYear() >= 2019 ) { 
                    $scope.events.push(myEvent);
                }

        });

    });


    /* alert on eventClick */
    $scope.alertOnEventClick = function( date, jsEvent, view){
        $scope.alertMessage = (date.title + ' was clicked ');
        alert(date.title + ' was clicked ');
    };
    /* alert on Drop */
     $scope.alertOnDrop = function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view){
       $scope.alertMessage = ('Event Droped to make dayDelta ' + delta);
    };
    /* alert on Resize */
    $scope.alertOnResize = function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ){
       $scope.alertMessage = ('Event Resized to make dayDelta ' + delta);
    };

    /* Change View */
    $scope.changeView = function(view,calendar) {
        alert("change View");
      uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('changeView',view);
    };

    /* Change View */
    $scope.renderCalender = function(calendar) {
    alert("change View render");
      if(uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar]){
        uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('render');
      }
    };

     /* Render Tooltip */
    $scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) { 
        element.attr({'tooltip': event.title,'tooltip-append-to-body': true});
        $compile(element)($scope);

    };


    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 600,
        editable: false,
        weekends: true,
        defaultView: 'month',
        lazyFetching: 'false',
        displayEventTime: false,
        header:{
          left: 'title',
          center: '',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender
      }
    };


    /* event sources array*/
        $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

});
```

Would have any idea what i'm missing ?

thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: the basic issue here appears to be that you are feeding the calendar a set of static data. Take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. If you define your event source as a dynamic using one of the two methods described in those links, then whenever you change the view (by pressing next/previous or any other way), fullCalendar will automatically go back to the data source you have defined and ask it for more events to cover the new time period which is on display.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I destroyed the callender and then recreate it for next and prev event ,and its work for me!

Comment: You mean everytime you click Next / Prev ?
could be ok, do you an example please ? ;)

Comment: this is not an efficient solution and should not be necessary. Using either https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function to define the source of events dynamically is the recommended method to give events to the calendar, and removes the need to keep re-creating the whole calendar, which is clearly not what the designers would have intended.

Comment: I used jquery and datepicker , then in next event I used .remove().append() and it was OK!!